# How to create circular "returning" arrows in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I want to draw something like this:

[image: Indentity map]

But when I use the *bezier curves and straight lines* tool, I'm getting lines that are not round enough:

[image: My attempt]

(And if I use several points, it's still ugly.) How can I make the arrows as in that picture?

Comment: Draw a cricle and cut it up?

Comment: Just for the sake of the curiosity: have you experienced problems by using the [control points](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Bezier-Curves.html)?

Answer (score 11):

Or, instead of using the regular bezier path option, you can use the spiro path option. Curves created with the spiro option are often pretty. I have it on by default. :-) [Although, personally, I'd create my own arrowheads from small triangles (instead of ending markers) so I can have full control of arrow position and angle.]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE5qR.png)

Answer (score 3):

The circle tool has 3 options: Full circle, piece of cake or arc. 
Use arc and then switch to node-view, and deform it a little, to make it look more sketchy. The arrow is in the color dialog, pattern of contour, if I translate correctly.